# Android Sync Draw and Update

Tags: android, null, draw, game-loop

I have a reset button for a game I am developing.  The button just removes things from the game to restore it to the original state.  However, I am having issues with Null Pointers when trying to do this.  I have a destroy() method in each object I am getting rid of that sets all the pointers it has to null.  And then I set all references to that object to null.  However, I sometimes receive these null exceptions in the draw method of the object being removed.  The only thing I can think of is that the update method sets the object's attributes to null, but before I can set game panel's reference to the object to null, the draw method is called, sees that the object is not null, and then attempts to call its draw methods (which causes the null errors).  But I don't see how that could happen.  Here is an excerpt from the AsyncTask I am using to run the game loop:

```
try {
            synchronized (surfaceHolder) {
                skipped = 0;

                long currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
                long frameTime = currentTime - previousFrameTime;
                previousFrameTime = currentTime;

                gamePanel.update(frameTime / 1000.0);
                canvas = surfaceHolder.lockCanvas();
                gamePanel.draw(canvas);
                surfaceHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);

                sleep = (int)(TARGET_FRAME_PERIOD - frameTime);

                if (sleep > 0) {
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(sleep);
                    } catch(InterruptedException e) {}
                }
            }
} finally {}
```